# Expect scripting basics

Tags: expect

I am new to Expect scripting and I would like to know any link where I can start with the basics of Expect scripting.

1. Syntax of commands
2. How to run and test the script.

Answer (score 4):

Get the book *[Exploring Expect](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do)*. Expect is an extension of [Tcl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl), so go through the [Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html).

A quick tutorial on how to make a script executable:

1. You need a "shebang" line to let the OS know how to interpret your script
2. You need to give the file executable permissions
3. You need to put the script in a directory that's in your $PATH, or invoke it with a full or relative path.

```
$ cat > test.exp << END
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
send_user "hello world\n"
END
$ chmod a+x test.exp
$ ./test.exp
hello world
```

While you are developing and testing your Expect script, put

```
exp_internal 1
```

at the beginning.

Comment: Hi,Can you tell me how to run the Expect script file?

Comment: Hi Glenn, Thank you very much for the support. May i know the need for exp_internal 1?

Comment: The 'exp_internal 1' line causes further commands to send diagnostic information internal to Expect to stderr. Its not debugging per se, but it provides some logging of the expect processing.